# objective-c's __kindof in C#

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.mac

I have no experience in objective c and am trying to translate a class written in objective c to c#. In the objective C class there is the "__kindof" keyword, such as

```
- (NSArray<__kindof NSViewController *> *)popToViewController:(__kindof NSViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

I researched about this keyword, and the documentation says that it allows NSViewController's subclass to be passed as parameter or element in the array. So I am wondering if there is a similar thing in C#. If not, are we allowed to just pass subclass of NSViewController as this method's parameter or the NSArray's element?

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly talking about `Inheritance` by means of inheriting a `abstract` base class or implementing a `Interface`. Then you can pass in a sub-class instance in place of base-class.

Something like below:

```
public interface INSViewController { ... }

public class ChildNSViewController : INSViewController {... } 

//Your method definition

public IEnumerable<INSViewController> popToViewController(INSViewController arg) {... }
```

You can call this method  now with child type as parameter

```
popToViewController(new ChildNSViewController())
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I am wondering if there is a similar thing in C#.

Not as such. Effectively `__kindof` allows a cast which might fail to be omitted - hopefully because the code has done a test and knows it won't.

> > For example: if `Y` is a subclass of `X` and you have a variable of type `X` then you can test if it is a `Y`, cast to `Y`, and call a `Y` method. If the variable has type `__kindof X` then the cast step can be omitted. Objective-C however does not statically enforce the test step, relying on runtime tests to catch any error.

C# 7's pattern matching feature can be used to do something sort-of similar, in that you can test (in an `if` or `switch`) if something is of a particular type and bind a name to it as that type - so again avoid casts after the test. Unlike the Objective-C feature the test part is required.

> If not, are we allowed to just pass subclass of NSViewController as this method's parameter or the NSArray's element?

Yes. In your C# code you might require casts/`is`/`as` uses that are implicit in Objective-C - unless you favour `dynamic` and run time tests.

HTH